# Sveltekit: Can't call API from +layout.ts. Error: "Failed to parse URL from /api/..."

Tags: api, sveltekit

This is the code in my `+layout.ts`

```
import type { LayoutLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutLoad = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/thumbnails', { method: 'GET' })
    if (response.ok) {
        return { json: await response.json() }
    }
    else {
        console.log('There were no blog posts to get.')
        // TODO: do something!
    }
};
```

I had the exact same code in a +page.ts file (the only difference was `LayoutLoad` was changed to `PageLoad`), and it worked there. I was calling my thumbnails api and populating my page. I don't understand why it doesn't work at all in +layout. It just crashes my web app.

On top of this, LayoutLoad has an error in VsCode that reads `Module '"./$types"' has no exported member 'LayoutLoad'`. I don't understand why this is. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the answer was here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests

> To get data from an external API or a +server.js handler, you can use the provided fetch function, which behaves identically to the native fetch web API with a few additional features:

Basically, in my code I had to change this line

`export const load: LayoutLoad = async () => {`

to this

`export const load: LayoutLoad = async ({fetch}) => {`

Because without that change I was using the native fetch and not sveltekit's provided fetch.

Also, I seemed to have fixed this error: `Module '"./$types"' has no exported member 'LayoutLoad'` by updating sveltkit to the latest version.